# Add custom icons with Material Icons

Tags: css, svg, material-design, google-material-icons

I am using the official google material icons: https://material.io/icons/

I want add some icons created by me, in svg.

how can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are using one of the existing icons? They come as web font, SVG and PNG. Guessing your using the font?

Comment: @NickSlash I want use as web font

Comment: Did you succeed with this? I have the same problem and would like to know if a solution exists

Comment: @Antonio, you are expressing conflicting wishes. On the original post you write that you wish to use SVG icons. But in your reply to NickSlash you write that you want to use them as webfont. These are different techniques, both officially supported by Material 2. If you wish to implement a webfont, NickSlash's reply below is adequate. If you wish to use the icons as SVGs, [this is a helpful source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/icon/icon-demo.ts)

Answer (score 6):

You will need to create your own web font.

If you've already got SVGs then you can possibly use something like https://icomoon.io/app/ to create one. I've not used it so can't help any further with that.

If not, you'll need to find a font authoring tool that exports to woff or woff2 or whatever web font format you need. (I think the material one is woff2)

Answer (score -7):

About more it [enter link description here](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <i class="material-icons md-light md-inactive">face</i>
</body>
</html>
```